# How to view HTTP Headers in CouchDB 2.0 logs?

Tags: logging, http-headers, couchdb

I am working on writing an integration test using karma and jasmine for my AngularJS application. My application uses PouchDB to connect to a CouchDB server.

I am experiencing trouble placing a PouchDB request from my application running in karma and would like to see the full HTTP Headers that the CouchDB server is requesting.

I tried setting the log level to `debug` but when I look at my log files I see entries such as this one that are missing the headers:

```
Mar 28 17:43:00 localhost docker: [notice] 2018-03-28T17:43:00.197305Z nonode@nohost <0.252.173> 589d57bb7e localhost:5984 10.0.2.2 undefined OPTIONS /q-21test/_design/dgf/_view/surgery_case_by_dtstart?include_docs=true&startkey=%222018-04-08T00%3A00%3A00-04%3A00T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%22&endkey=%222018-02-25T00%3A00%3A00-05%3A00T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%22&_nonce=1522258983997 405 ok 2
```

Comment: Send your request to CouchDB server with `curl` for example: `$ curl -v -X GET http://192.168.1.106:5984/sample/_all_docs` in which the `-v` option of curl shows the request and response headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to members of the #couchdb IRC channel, it is *not* possible to view HTTP request headers in the CouchDB logs.

As a workaround, I used `ngrep`:

```
sudo ngrep -q -d lo0 -Wbyline 'HTTP' 'port 5984' > out.txt
```

This command tells ngrep to capture HTTP traffic on localhost port 5984 and write it out output file `out.txt`. Note that I ran this command on a mac and that your network device (`-d` flag) could be different depending on your system.